# Change the color of another cell based on value of 2 columns in excel data sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need to update the Workproduct status in Column B based on status of the column L & M.

Workproduct status is to be Red if any of the cell value of Column L has the Value "Q" and Any of the cell value of M is  "NOTOK"

if Column L has the Value no values or empty " " and M has the value "NOTOK"
Workproduct status is to be filled with No color but this should not overwrite the previous condition i.e. if first condition is already true in any cells of L and M, Status update in column B has remain with that status.
other wise it has Workproduct status cell which is in column B should have no color.

How to update this code? It is not working

```
   Column B   |    Column L| Column M
----------------------------------------
1> Red        |       "Q"  |  "NOTOK" 
2> None       |       ""   |  "NOTOK"
---------------------------------------
```

But if first condition is already exists in an array of column L and M Then it should color red should be retained in column B

Comment: You missed to add the code. Anyhow: Why not using conditional formatting for that?

Answer (score 0):

Please try.

```vb
Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, RowOffset As Long
    Dim arrData, rngData As Range
    Const KEY_COLM = "NOTOK"
    Const KEY_COLQ = "Q"
    ' Get the data range of column L:M
    Set rngData = Application.Intersect(Range("L:M"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    arrData = rngData.Value
    RowOffset = rngData.Row - 1
    ' Loop through each row
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        If arrData(i, 2) = KEY_COLM Then
            If arrData(i, 1) = KEY_COLQ Then
                ' Fill with Red
                Cells(RowOffset + i, "B").Interior.Color = vbRed
            ElseIf Len(Trim(arrData(i, 1))) = 0 Then
                ' Clear filling
                Cells(RowOffset + i, "B").Interior.Pattern = xlNone
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```